# How to detect pressed key on BlackBerry using JQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, blackberry, jquery-mobile, keyevent

I am using JQuery Mobile to developing my own app for BlackBerry based on WebWorks(HTML5,CSS3,JS) tecknologies.

On my layout div i have 3 input elements.
I am wont to detect BlackBerry enter key pressed in first input to focus on next input.

How i can check if hardware enter key(and other keys like "T","R","D") pressed using JQuery Mobile??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing specific to jQuery Mobile for this. You just need to add an event listener on the input and listen to the appropriate keypress event. You can find a nice explanation for them [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html).

Here's some sample code to get you started (not tested, you might need to debug):

```
$('#firstInput').keypress(function(event) {
  if ( event.which === 13 ) {
     $('#secondInput').focus();
   }
);
```

In the `event.which`, the key code gets checked (13 is for enter). Other keys have different key codes. Be careful, I remember a bug on Blackberry that it wouldn't trigger the keypress event for backspace.

Be more specific about your problem if you need more details.